# How to take data from textarea and decrypt using javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I need to take data from a textarea on a website and decrypt it using a simple algorithm. The data is in the form of numbers separated by a comma. It also needs to read a space as a space. It looks like 42,54,57, ,57,40,57,44.
Heres what I have so far:

```
var my_textarea = $('textarea[name = "words"]').first();
var my_value = $(my_textarea).val();
var my_array = my_value.split(",");

for (i=0; i < my_array.length; i++)
{
var nv = my_array - 124;
var acv = nv + 34;
var my_result = String.fromCharCode(acv);
}

prompt("", my_result);
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: That's not decryption. At best it's de-obfuscation.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq]. While I'm happy that you've at least provided some code for your question, you haven't actually asked a question. Please do so.

Comment: @MarcB, I think OP meant "parse".

Comment: Sorry about the terminology. What I would like to know is how to put each one of the numbers through the for loop and then have its ascii value print to a prompt window. It should turn into a sentence when its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you were doing with the `nv` and `acv` variables, but I got your code working with a bit of modification.

Firstly, you need to refer to the individual array piece with `my_array[i]` inside your for loop.  Secondly, it will not treat a blank space as a space unless you tell it to - you need to put in a check for a blank space, and turn it into a space character(32).

The completed(and working) code is thus:

```
var my_textarea = $('textarea[name = "words"]').first();
var my_value = $(my_textarea).val();
var my_array = my_value.split(",");
var my_result = '';
for (i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    if (my_array[i] == ' ') {
        my_array[i] = 32;
    }
    var acv = my_array[i];
    my_result += String.fromCharCode(acv);

}
prompt("", my_result);​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BCpJQ/)